# Customise ant.design components style

Tags: antd

I read about few of the posts for custom theme and styles from less variables But can I modify at the level of say

```
.ant-collapse > .ant-collapse-item > .ant-collapse-header .arrow {
  right: 16px; // instead of left:16px
}
```

What do I want? In this specific case I just want my arrow to show on right instead of left in `Collapse.Panel` component.

From where from I copied the styles? In the component's `.css` itself.

This even if possible via `.less` modification and compiling may not be best solution, so open to hearing the workarounds, if any?

In less file, same would translate to

```
 right: @padding-md; // instead of original entry of left:  @padding-md;
```

and in customization guides, I can modify only variables. Now?

Comment: You have to change it globally=> 
:global(.ant-collapse-header) {
    //new style with important conswideration
}

Answer (score 1):

Write the below code in css file

```
:global {
 .ant-collapse-header{
    //code
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question but what about implementing your own  Collaps.panel?

```
import 'myPanelStyle.css'
export default class MyCollapsePanel{
  render(){
    return(<Collapse.panel id="my-panle" {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Collapse.panel>)
  }
}
```

myPanle.css:

```
#my-panle{
  .ant-collapse > .ant-collapse-item > .ant-collapse-header .arrow {
    right: 16px; // instead of left:16px
  }
}
```

in this way, anytime you use your panel it will be as you wish and you are not corrupt any other css sheets of default Antd library.